# Get average of each day in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to find an efficient way in Javascript/jQuery to do the following:

I got an array with objects each containing a date and a rating. Many entries have the same date. I'd like to create another array of objects, each containing date(unique) and an average of all ratings of that day.

Example data:

```
var array = [{
    date: "07-08-2018"
    rating: 3
    },{
    date: "07-08-2018"
    rating: 5
    },{
    date: "08-08-2018"
    rating: 2
    },{
    date: "08-08-2018"
    rating: 1
    },{
    date: "09-08-2018"
    rating: 3
    },{
    date: "09-08-2018"
    rating: 5
    }
]
```

What I'm after:

```
var averageArray = [{
    date: "07-08-2018",
    rating: 4
    },{
    date: "08-08-2018",
    rating: 1.5
    },{
    date: "09-08-2018",
    rating: 4
    }]
```

My current code (only returns 2 values instead of 3)

```
var oldDate = new Date(array[0].date);
var sum = 0;
var counter = 0
var newArray = []

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var date = new Date(array[i].date);

    if(date > oldDate){
        console.log("new day");
        var avg = (sum/counter);
        //console.log(avg);
        var newObject = new Object({
            date: date,
            rating: avg
        });
        newArray.push(newObject);
        counter = 0;
        sum = 0;
        oldDate = date;
    }
    counter++;
    sum = sum + array[i].rating;
    console.log(counter + " " + sum)
}

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and outline where you are having trouble. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for others to help you improve **your code** when it's not working as expected

Comment: forgot about that, just added my current code. It only return two values in the final array, and it feels like a lot of lines are required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to group things is by creating an object that uses the common values as property keys.

Then after you have them grouped in that object map the results to new array

```js
var tmp ={};

data.forEach(function(item){
  // if property for current date already exists  we update existing otherwise start new one
  var obj =  tmp[item.date] = tmp[item.date] || {count:0, total: 0};
  // increment count and total of all the ratings
  obj.count ++;
  obj.total += item.rating

});

var res = Object.entries(tmp).map(function(entry){
    return { date: entry[0], ave: entry[1].total/entry[1].count}
})

console.log( res)
```

```html
<script>
var data = [{
    date: "07-08-2018",
    rating: 3
    },{
    date: "07-08-2018",
    rating: 5
    },{
    date: "08-08-2018",
    rating: 2
    },{
    date: "08-08-2018",
    rating: 1
    },{
    date: "09-08-2018",
    rating: 3
    },{
    date: "09-08-2018",
    rating: 5
    }
]
</script>
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Can you elaborate a little bit on what's happening on this line: var obj =  tmp[item.date] = tmp[item.date] || {count:0, total: 0};

Comment: Sure. It's shorthand for `if(tmp[item.date]){ tmp[item.date] = tmp[item.date]/* equals existing*/}else{tmp[item.date] = {/* new object*/} }`. Then `var obj = tmp[item.date]` just to make it shorter to write update of the property values

Comment: Throw in a `console.log(tmp)` and see what it looks like

Comment: Thanks! I learned a new shorthand instead of using the ternary operators with `?` and `:`.